# Using SwiftUI with a HUD

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I created a SwiftUI-based, HUD class (based on [SwiftyHUDView](https://github.com/antranapp/SwiftyHUDView)):

```swift
struct ActivityIndicatorView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
   
    var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                self.content()
                    .disabled(self.isShowing)
                    .blur(radius: self.isShowing ? 3 : 0)

                VStack {
                    Text("Loading...")
                    ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .large)
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2,
                       height: geometry.size.height / 5)
                .background(Color.secondary.colorInvert())
                .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first time I use this:

```swift
@ObservedObject var serviceManager = ServiceManager()

ActivityIndicatorView(isShowing: .constant(serviceManager.loading)) {
            NavigationView {
                ZStack {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: self.serviceFetch)

    private func serviceFetch() {
        serviceManager.loadSomeData()
    }
}

class ServiceManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var someData: [String] = []
    @Published var loading = false
    
    init() {
        loading = true
    }

    public func loadSomeData() {
       go get some data ...

       self.loading = false
    }
}
```

The HUD class works fine, it disappears once the service call has returned data.

However, if I attempt to use the ActivityIndicatorView a second time in a different screen, the HUD screen stays up, even after the service call returns data and the @Published loading value is set to false.

My question is this.  Because I am using *ActivityIndicatorView* a second time, is the publish/observable link, ie. the **loading** property which is marked @Published is changed once the data is returned, the view that has the *ActivityIndicatorView* and @ObservedObject ServiceManager that should update its view and is not, somehow broken or do I have to initialize *ActivityIndicatorView* a certain way because it is used multiple times?

Comment: Can you show how the `ActivityIndicatorView` is used on the different screen - i.e. the broken case. Also, why are you using `.constant` for the binding?

Comment: In regards to using .constant for the binding, the reason is: In ActivityIndicatorView, @Binding var isShowing: Bool is defined as a binding variable.  Classes interacting with this class are setting the value to either true or false (a Swift Bool value) and without the .constant, I get a "Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'" error.

Comment: `.constant` binding is meant for prototyping. Use the projected value of an `@ObservedObject`, which is a binding to the value: `ActivityIndicatorView(isShowing: $serviceManager.loading)`. Also, since `ActivityIndicatorView` doesn't modify the value, you don't need it to be a binding at all.